# Enter blank rows in a table using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I need to enter 20 blank rows at the 9th row of an existing table in an Excel sheet. My code so far is:

```
migration_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("ProjectName_Migration_Workbook.xlsx"))
ws = migration_workbook['sheet1']
print(ws.tables.items())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the table's name, you can access it through [`ws.tables`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.tables):

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("book.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
table = ws.tables['Table1']
```

To get its range you can do:

```
print(table.ref)
```

Which gives, for example:

```
D5:F11
```

Now, you can convert it to a `CellRange` to be able to change it and get the first row:

```
table_range = CellRange(table.ref)
print(table_range.min_row)
```

Will give:

```
5
```

So now to add empty rows, first [`expand`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.html#openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.CellRange.expand) the table:

```
table_range.expand(down=20)
table.ref = table_range.coord
```

And then add the actual rows to the sheet:

```
ws.insert_rows(table_range.min_row + 9, 20)
```

Don't forget to `wb.save` in the end.

---

Full example code:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange

start_row = 9
num_rows = 20

wb = load_workbook("book.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
table = ws.tables['Table1']

table_range = CellRange(table.ref)
table_range.expand(down=num_rows)
table.ref = table_range.coord

ws.insert_rows(table_range.min_row + start_row, num_rows)
wb.save("book.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 2):

I've not used this package before but reading the [`openpyxl` documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editing_worksheets.html), it looks like you could do something like this:

```
row_number = 9
insert_pt = row_number + 1
no_rows = 20

ws.insert_rows(insert_pt, no_rows)
```

OR Here is a solution using Pandas and Numpy:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read data
df = pd.read_excel("ProjectName_Migration_Workbook.xlsx")

# Create user-defined function 'blankRowInsert'
def blankRowInsert(df, insert_pt, no_rows)
    ip = insert_pt-1
    before_insert = ip
    no_insert = no_rows
    orig_rows = len(df)

    df_new = df.iloc[0:before_insert]

    for index in range(no_insert):
      df_new = df_new(pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * len(df_new.columns)], columns = df_new.columns, ), ingore_index=True
    
    df_new = df_new.append(df.iloc[ip:orig_rows], ignore_index = True)

    return(df_new)
    
# Test the function
new_df = blankRowInsert(df=df, insert_pt=9, no_rows = 20)
```

You could then use the following to write the new dataframe with inserted blank rows back to an excel file:

```
new_df.to_excel('your_new_excel_file.xlsx', index = False)
```